# Source for achdus being the only way klal yisroel could accept the Torah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, parashas-yisro

I heard someone say that the only way *klal yisroel* was able to accept the *Torah* was through *achdus*?

Does anyone know the source for this? Is it in *Chofetz Chaim Al HaTorah*?

Comment: Why do you think it might be hh al hatorah? Are you withholding information?

Answer (score 4):

[Rabbi Dovid Green quotes this idea in the name of the Slonimer Rebbe](http://www.torah.org/learning/dvartorah/5757/yisro.html):

> The prerequisite for accepting the Yoke of Torah is the commitment to unity.

See there for more on the topic.

In light of this, it illuminates the Midrash Chazal in the Mechilta (Yisro 19:2) ויחן שם ישראל נגד ההר - And Israel Encamped there, opposite the mountain. The Midrash; noting the usage of ויחן as opposed to the plural ויחנו, says this is meant to connote the unity the Jewish people felt prior to acceptance of the Torah - As one man, with one heart.

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/tm/8/27/210) from the Lubavitcher Rebbe:

> לקבלת התורה הוצרכה ההקדמה דאהבת ישראל
>
> To receive the Torah requires the preface of Ahavas Yisroel

The same idea is found (at the end of the following piece) from the [Rebbe Rashab](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/maharshab/terav/1/3).

It seems to be a common theme in Chassidic thought. The basis is [the Mechilta](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40608&st=&pgnum=91)<sup>1</sup> brought by Rashi on Shemos 19:2 (as brought in footnote 28 of the first link).

---

<sup>1. It can be found immediately preceding the beginning of פרשה ב.</sup>

Comment: Can you send me a link to the Mechilta brought by Rashi on Shemos 19:2?

Comment: "It seems to be a common theme in Chassidic thought": do you mean _Chabad chasidus_ or _chasidus_ in general?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah, the Mechilta is on Yisro 19:11, as brought in footnote 28 of the first link in the answer. I don't know of its availability online.

Comment: @msh210, given the quoting of the Slonimer Rebbe in the other answer, I am saying in general.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect comments 1 & 3